# Extract information in JSON format from Pandas Dataframe and Append to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Grateful for your help. I have data in JSON format within a dataframe. I'm trying to extract into new columns and append to the existing dataframe. Here's what my dataframe looks like:

| Company | Attribution |
| --- | --- |
| Papa John's | Papa John's JSON data |
| KFC | JSON data |

Here's what the JSON data looks like:

```
[{'domain':'papajohns.com','country':'USA'},{'domain':'papajohns.co.uk,'country':'UK}] [{'domain':'kfc.com','country':'USA'},{'domain':'kfc.co.uk,'country':'UK}]
```

And the results should be:

| Company | domain | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Papa John's | papajohns | USA |
| Papa John's | papajohns UK | UK |
| KFC | kfc | USA |
| KFC | kfc UK | UK |

The closest I've got to this is:

```
df_results = json_normalize(df1.to_dict('list'), ['Attribution'].unstack().apply(pd.Series)
```

But this does not append the Attribution columns to the Company columns. It does not seem to hit all rows, even when I've removed empty rows.

Other similar answers don't create new columns, based on the fields within the JSON.

Comment: I've voted to re-open. But please check if the duplicates help and show how far you get. Your "attempt" even has a syntax error.